# Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

In Python I am trying to remove rows of a dataframe if the dates are lower than the dates of another dataframe. But the comparison does not work.

Here are my two dataframes and the results I try to compare. `print(MeteoCH.head())` will result in:

> ```
>                        TempAvg  TempMin  TempMax
> Date                                                                      
> 2021-11-15 00:00:00      4.4      4.3      4.5     
> 2021-11-15 01:00:00      4.3      4.3      4.3     
> 2021-11-15 02:00:00      4.1      4.1      4.2     
> 2021-11-15 03:00:00      4.0      3.8      4.1    
> 2021-11-15 04:00:00      3.6      3.4      3.8
> ```

And `print(PicoLog.head())` will result in:

> ```
>                            Temp1   Temp2   Temp3   
> Date                                                                        
> 2021-11-15 18:34:18+01:00  21.268  21.671  21.190     
> 2021-11-15 18:34:20+01:00  21.266  21.673  21.194     
> 2021-11-15 18:34:22+01:00  21.270  21.680  21.194     
> 2021-11-15 18:34:24+01:00  21.263  21.673  21.180    
> 2021-11-15 18:34:26+01:00  21.262  21.672  21.185
> ```

If I try to execute the following command:

```
MeteoCH.drop(MeteoCH[MeteoCH.index < PicoLog.index.min()], inplace=True)
```

It results with the following error :

> TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and Timestamp

Why? How to solve it ?

I tried to "convert" it somehow, but it does not work.

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplier is filter by greater or equal, inverted `<` like:

```
MeteoCH[MeteoCH.index >= PicoLog.index.min()]

MeteoCH[~(MeteoCH.index < PicoLog.index.min())]
```

Your solution is possible change filtering `MeteoCH.index`, but in my opinion overcomplicated:

```
MeteoCH.drop(MeteoCH.index[MeteoCH.index < PicoLog.index.min()], inplace=True)
```

EDIT:

Original problem was timezone offset, solution is [`DatetimeIndex.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html):

```
PicoLog.index = PicoLog.index.tz_localize(None)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it does not work. If I type `MeteoCH[MeteoCH.index >= PicoLog.index.min()]`, I still have `TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and Timestamp`

Comment: @Elfo2285 - What is your pandas version?

Comment: ```$ pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.3.3```

Comment: @Elfo2285 - What is `print (MeteoCH.index.dtype)` and  `print (PicoLog.index.dtype)` ?

Comment: `print(MeteoCH.index.dtype)` --> `datetime64[ns]`    
`print(PicoLog.index.dtype)`   --> `datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]`

Comment: By the way, I should remove this fixedoffset. I do not know why it appears when I read my excel file...

Comment: @Elfo2285 - it should help. Try `PicoLog.index = PicoLog.index.tz_localize(None)` (like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198068/how-to-remove-timezone-from-a-timestamp-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe))