# If you have a dataframe with the a date format that has zone info. How to find the day name of all the crossponding data points?

Tags: python, time-series

I have a dataframe with the following format:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 23, 4, 59, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -25200))
```

How can I find the day name? I tried `.day_name()`, but for some reason when you have the zone data that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did and it worked for me. Thanks for the aforementioned solution, it works on a single data point, but for a dataframe here is what I did: say you have a dataframe df with the data in column 'Time', then:

df['Time']=df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=None)) # that takes out the zone time

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']) # to convert it to dtype

import datetime as dt

df['DayofWeek'] = df['Time'].dt.day_name() # make a new column with day name

Comment: There was good information in this thread as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198068/how-to-remove-timezone-from-a-timestamp-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe
and this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFuo7EHI8zc

Answer (score 2):

Try using
`object.strftime("%A")`
where object refer to instance of datetime

This will return the day name as in name of days in week

Answer (score 1):

You can use `weekday` to get a numeric day of the week. You can then use a dictionary to translate that to actual day names. Something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzoffset

date = datetime(2021, 3, 23, 4, 59, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -25200))
days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
print(days[date.weekday()])
```

Comment: So I have a dataframe that looks like this:
--------------------------

                           Load-kW
Time                                
2021-03-23 04:59:00-07:00  57.355556


2021-03-23 05:00:00-07:00  61.095000


2021-03-23 05:01:00-07:00  61.260000


2021-03-23 05:02:00-07:00  61.868333


2021-03-23 05:03:00-07:00  61.378333
----------------------/

and its shape is (619663, 2). How to find the day of the week for every corresponding data point?