# Pandas convert date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Hey guys I need some help, my date is not in the correct format.

I made a function to convert all columns of dates it works but, it gives a return of SettingWithCopyWarning.

[image: Origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xlT4.png)

[image: function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZe9f.png)

[image: warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iglZB.png)

can you tell me how to solve this I've tried in several ways.

Comment: could you please add code / examples as text instead of image? easy copy & paste in general allow to create better solutions.

Comment: regarding your problem, did you have a look at [How to remove timezone from a Timestamp column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49198068/10197418)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your code is working and is doing its job you can always ignore the error by adding this at the top. I would not recommend it in a very large scale project.

```
from pandas.core.common import SettingWithCopyWarning

warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=SettingWithCopyWarning)
```