# Have to convert it into date time format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the data and in that data, time date format is of type 2017-11-01 00:00:00-04:00. I want to strip -4:00 and have to use the remaining.

I did everything but no successs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198068/how-to-remove-timezone-from-a-timestamp-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Yes. its Timezone data; also see stackoverflow.com/questions/63305945

Comment: it's in string format

Comment: how to convert it into date time format?

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
date_string = '2017-11-01 00:00:00-04:00'
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')

print(date)
# Returns: 2017-11-01 00:00:00-04:00

print(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
# Retruns: 2017-11-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a column so how to change the column in this format?

Comment: df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date"],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"). I used this still it's not converting

Comment: OP's apparently using Pandas, which has more powerful tools for working with datetimes. Check out the question Nick linked: [How to remove timezone from a Timestamp column in a pandas dataframe](/q/49198068/4518341)

Comment: You can remove the tz_localize from the dtype this can be done as follows:

df['date'].dt.tz_localize(none)